# Proving that $\sup(S^2)=(\sup(S))^2$ for $S$ a subset of the reals with only nonnegative elements

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, proof-writing, solution-verification

Let $S^2=\{x^2:x\in S,x\geq 0\}$. Prove that $\sup(S^2)=(\sup(S))^2$.

Attempt: let $s=\sup(S)$. Then for any $x\in S$ we have $s\geq x$. Hence $s^2\geq x^2$. Therefore $s^2$ is an upper bound for $S^2$. Hence $(\sup(S))^2\leq \sup(S^2)$.

I want to prove the reverse inequality but cannot seem to get anywhere with this - any hints would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let $s = \text{sup}(S)$, as you have shown that $s^2$ is an upper bound for $S^2$,
we only need to show it is the smallest.

As the set contains only positive elements we can say $s \ge 0$ and $\sqrt{s}$ exists

Let $x$ be an upper bound then $\alpha^2 \le x \ \forall \alpha \in S $ and

$\alpha \le \sqrt{x}$ thus by definition of supremum we get $s \le \sqrt{x}$

or $s^2 \le x$ which proves the claim

Answer (score 0):

I think this question has a mistake in it. Let me give a counterexample for which $\sup(S^2) > (\sup(S))^2$, which would be the following. Let $S = \{\frac{1}{2}\}$. Since $\frac{1}{2}$ is greater than or equal to zero, then $S^2 = \{\frac{1}{2}\}$ as well. Both of these sets contain just one element, so their supremums are equal and equate simply to $\frac{1}{2}$. Therefore we obtain
$$\frac{1}{2} = \sup(S^2) > (\sup(S))^2 = \frac{1}{4}$$
which is a not consistent with the claim made.

Comment: probably he meant $S^2$ as the set with elements squared, which is shown in his working

Comment: Hi yeah I meant the elements squared, just edited the question:)

Comment: @Alidixon244 Ah, ok :) Thanks for the correction. Well, we can think along these lines. Since $sup(S^2)$ exists, then the set $S^2$ is not empty, which means that we have some non-negative elements in $S$. Thus, $sup(S)$ must necessarily be non-negative. By definition $sup(S^2)$ is also non-negative. Now let's assume that $(sup(S))^2 > sup(S^2)$. Both sides are non-negative, so I can take the square root, and we obtain $sup(S) > \sqrt{sup(S^2)} \geq 0$. Hence, there must exist some non-negative $x \in S$, such that $x > \sqrt{sup(S^2)}$. Therefore $x^2 > sup(S^2)$, which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

**Correction:** you actually proved the reverse proposition, $(\sup(S))^2 \geq \sup(S^2).$

**Hint:** to prove $(\sup(S))^2\leq \sup(S^2),$ you could try rewriting it as $\sup(S)\leq \sqrt{\sup(S^2)},$ and using essentially the same argument again.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to prove the reverse inequality but cannot seem to get anywhere with this - any hints would be great!

Just do it.

If $k <(\sup S)^2$ then if we assume $k\ge 0$ then $\sqrt{k} < \sup S$.  So $\sqrt{k}$ is not an upper bound of $S$.  So there exists a $w\in S$ so that $\sqrt k < w$. and $k < w^2 \in S^2$.   So $k$ is not an upper bound of $S$ if $k$ is positve.  And if $k$  is negative... well, it's obvious not an upper bound as it is *smaller* than all $y \in S^2$ which are all non-negative.

So no upper bound of $S^2$ is less than $(\sup S^2)$ so $\sup S^2 \le (\sup S^2)$.